# Manual line break in Glossaries name

Tags: line-breaking, glossaries

I found somewhere here a way to define my own glossary-style:

```
\newglossarystyle{superglossarystyle}
{
    \setglossarystyle{super}
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}
    {
        \tablehead{}
        \tabletail{}
        \begin{supertabular}{rp{\glsdescwidth}}
    }
    {
        \end{supertabular}
    }
}
%
\setglossarystyle{superglossarystyle}
```

How do I manually break a line in the `name`-field in `\newglossaryentry`?

How it looks now:

```
ParameterA,ParameterB  This is the description of ParameterA and ParameterB,
                       that is long and automatically wraps.

           ParameterC  This is the description of ParameterC, that is long
                       and automatically wraps.
```

How it should look:

```
ParameterA,
ParameterB   This is the description of ParameterA and ParameterB,
             that is long and automatically wraps.

ParameterC   This is the description of ParameterC, that is long
             and automatically wraps.
```

I tried to add `\\,\linebreak,\tabbreak` etc. as a line break without any success.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,oneside,12pt,halfparskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage[]{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3.6cm,bottom=3.6cm,left=3.6cm,right=3.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{superglossarystyle}
{
    \setglossarystyle{super}
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}
    {
        \tablehead{}
        \tabletail{}
        \begin{supertabular}{cp{\glsdescwidth}}
    }
    {
        \end{supertabular}
    }
}

\setglossarystyle{superglossarystyle}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{pab}
{
    name        = {$\boldsymbol{ParameterA},\boldsymbol{ParameterB}$} ,
    description = {This is the description of ParameterA and ParameterB, that is long and automatically wraps} ,
}

\newglossaryentry{pc}
{
    name        = {$\boldsymbol{ParameterC}$} ,
    description = {This is the description of ParameterC, that is long and automatically wraps.} ,
}

\begin{document}

\glsaddallunused\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you describe more precisely how you generated such entries.  This would be best done by including a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: You can't have a line break in a column defined with the `r` specifier. You'd have to switch to a paragraph specifier, such as `p` (as with the second column).

Comment: Okay, then how do I get something like `\glsnamewidth` and right-align a `p{}`?

Answer (score 4):

The standard column specifiers are `l`, `r`, `c` and `p{`*length*`}`. You can define new column types using the [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package, but I don't think that's needed in this case as you can adjust the paragraph alignment using `\raggedleft`. When defining a new glossary style, it helps to consider a simplified version of what that style does. At it's basic level, the style needs to be in the form:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{4cm}}
\raggedleft A. & some text\\
\raggedleft AA. & some more text\\
\raggedleft AAA. & some more text
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which has a right-aligned paragraph-style first column.

[image: Image where first column is right aligned]

Now test what happens if `ParameterA,ParameterB` is added:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{4cm}}
\raggedleft A. & some text\\
\raggedleft AA. & some more text\\
\raggedleft AAA. & some more text\\
\raggedleft ParameterA,ParameterB & some text
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This doesn't have a line wrap because TeX can't insert a line break, so the result is rather ugly.

[image: Image with overfull line]

Instead you need to provide TeX with some scope to break the line at the comma:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\comma}{,\penalty \exhyphenpenalty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{4cm}}
\raggedleft A. & some text\\
\raggedleft AA. & some more text\\
\raggedleft ParameterA\comma ParameterB & some text
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

TeX can now break the line:

[image: Image with line break after comma]

Here I've hardcoded the column widths using `2cm` and `4cm`, but the `glossaries` package defines a length for the second column called `\glsdescwidth`. You can define another length to use for the first column:

```
\newlength\glsnamewidth
```

You'll need to set this value as appropriate for your document. For example:

```
\setlength{\glsnamewidth}{3cm}
```

or

```
\setlength{\glsnamewidth}{0.3\hsize}
```

The new glossary style can then be defined as:

```
\newglossarystyle{superglossarystyle}
{%
  \setglossarystyle{super}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {%
      \tablehead{}%
      \tabletail{}%
      \begin{supertabular}{p{\glsnamewidth}p{\glsdescwidth}}%
  }%
  {%
      \end{supertabular}%
  }%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \raggedleft
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}
```

The complete example is:

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,oneside,12pt,halfparskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage[]{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3.6cm,bottom=3.6cm,left=3.6cm,right=3.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}

\newcommand{\comma}{,\penalty \exhyphenpenalty}
\newlength\glsnamewidth
\setlength{\glsnamewidth}{0.3\hsize}

\newglossarystyle{superglossarystyle}
{%
  \setglossarystyle{super}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
  {%
      \tablehead{}%
      \tabletail{}%
      \begin{supertabular}{p{\glsnamewidth}p{\glsdescwidth}}%
  }%
  {%
      \end{supertabular}%
  }%
  \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \raggedleft
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
  }%
}

\setglossarystyle{superglossarystyle}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{pab}
{
    name        =
{$\boldsymbol{ParameterA}\comma\boldsymbol{ParameterB}$} ,
    description = {This is the description of ParameterA and
ParameterB, that is long and automatically wraps} ,
}

\newglossaryentry{pc}
{
    name        = {$\boldsymbol{ParameterC}$} ,
    description = {This is the description of ParameterC, that is
long and automatically wraps.} ,
}

\begin{document}

\glsaddallunused\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image: Image of glossary]

Comment: Thank you, I use your example + `\null\newline` in front of the description of the `pab`-entry for better alignment (its okay for the few occourences of this, I guess it'll be much harder to do this automatically).