# Line break inside (long) name in glossary entry

Tags: line-breaking, glossaries

The solution to ["manual break in glossaries name"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203718/manual-line-break-in-glossaries-name) does not print any glossaries in my case (after adding `\gls{pab}` and `\gls{pc}` just after `\begin{document}`). If I define the name as a tabular environment, it works for one entry, but for the second: I get a compile error. So it's probably a bad lead. What other options are there?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% also see
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203718/manual-line-break-in-glossaries-name

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-foo.glo}
\newglossaryentry{lorem}
{
  type=foo,
  name={                                % Method
    % Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,       % lb         % FAIL
    %   \\ consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
\begin{tabular}{l}                      % tabular+lb % OK (it seemed)
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\\ 
  consectetuer adipiscing elit.
\end{tabular} 
},
  text={Lorem ipsum dolor \dots.},
  description={}
}

\newglossaryentry{utpurus}
{
  type=foo,
  name={                                % Method
\begin{tabular}{l}                      % tabular+lb    % FAIL
  Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, \\
  adip iscing vitae, felis.
\end{tabular} 
},
  text={Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,\dots},
  description={}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=altlist]{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries
% \setglossarystyle{tree}
\newglossary*{foo}{Foo}
\loadglsentries[foo]{\jobname-foo.glo}

\begin{document}

\gls{lorem}
%\gls{utpurus} % ERROR: Improper alphabetic constant.

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prepared a simple MWE that follows the recipe for breaking long glossary names using `tabular`.

It may be helpful to check your settings. (compile, run `makeglossaries`, compile again)

[image: A]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries %<<< use this

\newglossaryentry{foo}{name={foo},text={Only foo.}, description={Something else}}

\newglossaryentry{lorem}
{%
    name={%                           
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l}    % use @{} to suppress the space                
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\\ 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        \end{tabular} 
    },
    text={Lorem ipsum dolor \dots.},
    description={}
}

\newglossaryentry{utpurus}
{ %
    name={ %              
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l}                     
            Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, \\ placerat ac, \\
            adip iscing vitae, felis.
        \end{tabular} 
    },
    text={Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,\dots},
    description={}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item  \gls{foo}     
    \item  \gls{lorem}   
    \item  \gls{utpurus}
\end{itemize}       

\printglossary %<<< use this

\end{document}
```

Comment: `foo` was meant as a glossary, not a glossary entry, and the data is pulled from a file with `filecontents`. It's possible that's not a mwe, I'll check, but your solution does not show to solve my problem at hand (I'll check too but I need to study `glossaries` for use with `\makeglossaries` instead of `\makenoidxglossaries`).

Comment: Your new code runs OK, so problem solved?. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

@Simon Dispa's answer and my comment to it combined:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossary*{foo}{Foo}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-foo.glo}
\newglossaryentry{lorem}
{%
    type=foo,
    name={%                           
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l}                    
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\\ 
            consectetuer adipiscing elit.
        \end{tabular} 
    },
    text={Lorem ipsum dolor \dots.},
    description={}
}
\newglossaryentry{utpurus}
{ %
    type=foo,
    name={ %              
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l}                     
            Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, \\ placerat ac, \\
            adip iscing vitae, felis.
        \end{tabular} 
    },
    text={Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,\dots},
    description={}
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\loadglsentries[foo]{\jobname-foo.glo}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\DTMnow 

\begin{itemize}
%    \item  \gls{foo}     
    \item  \gls{lorem}   
    \item  \gls{utpurus}
\end{itemize}       

\printglossary[type=foo]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, I tested the original code with `@{}l` in place of `l` (and and added `\\` where applicable), that did not solve the problem, which points to a `\makenoidxglossaries` issue.